# JavaScript/HTML- how to disabled an item of a list

Tags: javascript, html, list, grails

I have to disable the above item

```
  <li style="background-color: #CCCCCC" disabled="disabled">As your company</li>
```

As you can see I tried to use the disabled attribute but when I click on this item the function which called onclick is still called.

```
<fieldset style="display: inline" >
    <div class="ui-grid-a" style="display: inline">
        <label class="text-ligh ui-block-a">Post as: </label>
        <label class="link toggle-post ui-block-b" >Yourself</label>
    </div>
    %{--<div data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">--}%
        %{--<h3 id="listHeader">Yourself</h3>--}%
        <ul class="ul-post" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" onclick="changeHeader(event);" style="width: 240%; display:none">
            <li data-postas="0">Yourself</li>
            <g:if test="${companyList?.size() > 1}">
                <li style="background-color: #CCCCCC" disabled="disabled">As your company</li>
                <g:each var="company" in="${companyList}">
                    <li data-postas="1" value="${company?.id}" id="${company?.companyname}" data-company="${company?.id}">${company?.companyname}</li>
                </g:each>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <input type="hidden" value="${companyList[0].id}" name="company"/>
            </g:else>

        </ul>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Check for disabled attribute in the function and return false ?

Comment: What does this syntax mean? <g:else> ... it is not standard HTML, is it?

Comment: grails..... it's condition

Answer (score 1):

The `disabled` attribute is valid only on interactive form elements (`<input />`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc); to 'disable' the `<li>` from firing assigned click events you'll have to filter out the 'disabled' `<li>` elements in your click-handler:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':not([data-interactivity="disabled"])')) {
    console.log(this.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>This element is click-able.</li>
  <li data-interactivity="disabled">This element is not.</li>
</ul>
```

Or from the jQuery collection before you attach your click-handler:

```js
$('li').not('[data-interactivity="disabled"]').on('click', function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>This element is click-able.</li>
  <li data-interactivity="disabled">This element is not.</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).
  - [Using `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).
- jQuery:

  - [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
  - [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: "*It's not working*" where? Here in the demos, or in your site? How, precisely, is "*[it] not working*"?

Comment: In the demo, in the question itself? My JavaScript console begs to differ, since it's showing the relevant `textContent` on clicking the 'clickable' (first) `<li>`. What browser are you using, have you opened your JS console (F12), are there any errors reported or triggered?

Comment: in the  Demo.  Also i tried it in my code and the function is still called

Comment: Are you deliberately only answering one question at a time? I'm not asking for fun, but because I want to (at least *try* to) help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try preventDefault for this. This will stop default action of anchor tag.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("#projectLi").on("click",function(event){
     console.log("preventing default");
     event.preventDefault();
     //event.stopPropagation();

    });
});
```